# Adding/Keeping tracking parameters to URL's through redirects with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have a site `domain.com/contact` that sends users to another blank site `site.com/save-form` after a form is submitted and then redirects back to the original domain `domain.com/thank-you`.

So it goes `domain.com/contact >> site.com/save-form >> domain.com/thank-you`

For tracking I need to pass the cookie ID to the URL and I can do that when the user performs in action. In this case after the user submits the form. I have a javascript function that decorates the URL.

The trouble I am having is the middle redirecting page. It just loads quickly and then redirects to final page `domain.com/thank-you`. How can I append the parameter from the first page to the middle page `site.com/save-form` and pass it to `domain.com/thank-you`. I was trying to think through various onload functions but was having trouble coming up with a solid answer or topics to research.

Also I would like to do this in JavaScript if possible. I don't think I can edit anything on the server side.

Thanks

Comment: If you can't control the server, you can't do what you ask. But if you save a cookie on the first page `domain.com/contact` that cookie will be available on the third page `domain.com/thank-you`.

Comment: Thanks! The only problem with just cookieing is that it will look like a visitor came from site.com as a new referral instead of a continued visit.